# filter array based on other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have 2 arrays of different URLs, on possibly same images

```
const images1 = [
  "https://somelink222/01ao00/5363c2ba39696bd76d6dd1a25ab49609.jpeg",
  "https://somelink222/01ao00/b8d695c4ea5f1c141e5d54b4c50bcd78.jpeg"
]

// denne skal filtreres
const images2 = [
  {location: "https://otherLink1/01ao00/5363c2ba39696bd76d6dd1a25ab49609.jpeg"},
  {location: "https://otherLink1/01ao00/f2cdeaf286a7636c8b3010e34acae475.jpeg"},
  {location: "https://otherLink1/01ao00/b8d695c4ea5f1c141e5d54b4c50bcd78.jpeg"}
]
```

I want to filter images2 so if any of the file names e.g. "01ao00/5363c2ba39696bd76d6dd1a25ab49609.jpeg" are contained in images1

Comment: Look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Please read the [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: @psdpainter you misjudged his question

Comment: @MisterJojo Can you explain? I only see a task dump/question for a free coding service without any effort. Do you see more? _"Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ is pretty clear in this case.

Comment: @jabaa you are very severe! this question is a little more subtle than using the array.filter method directly; without being considered as a request for free code, you just need to have a good knowledge of the possibilities on the array. It's a matter of learning

Comment: @MisterJojo There are many websites for this type of question but Stack Overflow expects research effort to keep this high quality. There are rules to ensure that homework dumps and requests for code writing are downvoted, closed and deleted. You can't use a platform and break the rules just because it's too difficult for you. An approach with two nested loops would solve the problem and can be programmed by most junior developers.

Comment: just to inform, I have tried for many hours, but wanted to simplify the question in order not to confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply

```js
const images1 = 
  [ "https://somelink222/01ao00/5363c2ba39696bd76d6dd1a25ab49609.jpeg"
  , "https://somelink222/01ao00/b8d695c4ea5f1c141e5d54b4c50bcd78.jpeg"
  ] 
const images2 = 
  [ { location: "https://otherLink1/01ao00/5363c2ba39696bd76d6dd1a25ab49609.jpeg"} 
  , { location: "https://otherLink1/01ao00/f2cdeaf286a7636c8b3010e34acae475.jpeg"} 
  , { location: "https://otherLink1/01ao00/b8d695c4ea5f1c141e5d54b4c50bcd78.jpeg"} 
  ] 


const result = images2.filter( el =>
  {
  let img = el.location.split('/').pop()
  return images1.some(x=>x.includes(img))
  })


console.log ( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: cool. I can see that I was close. Will try it out later today

Answer (score 0):

```
const images1 = [
    'https://somelink222/01ao00/5363c2ba39696bd76d6dd1a25ab49609.jpeg',
    'https://somelink222/01ao00/b8d695c4ea5f1c141e5d54b4c50bcd78.jpeg',
];

// denne skal filtreres
const images2 = [
    { location: 'https://otherLink1/01ao00/5363c2ba39696bd76d6dd1a25ab49609.jpeg' },
    { location: 'https://otherLink1/01ao00/f2cdeaf286a7636c8b3010e34acae475.jpeg' },
    { location: 'https://otherLink1/01ao00/b8d695c4ea5f1c141e5d54b4c50bcd78.jpeg' },
];

const img1_reduce_data = images1.map(val => val.split('/').pop());
const res = images2.filter(val => img1_reduce_data.includes(val.location.split('/').pop()));
console.log(res);
```